# Loading property from local.properties not working in Gradle Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to include master branch of one Github project that cloned in my local system. The project is in a different directory than my project. While trying to include this in my project I get the following error -

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

To include the project, I am doing the following -

app/build.gradle

```
compile project(':sugar')
```

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':sugar'

def getLocalProperty(prop) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(new File(rootDir.absolutePath + '/local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    return properties.getProperty(prop, '')
}

project(':sugar').projectDir = new File(getLocalProperty('sugar.dir'))
```

local.properties

```
sugar.dir="/home/jaibatrik/StudioProjects/sugar/library"
```

**Note**: It works well, if in settings.gradle, I directly use

```
project(':sugar').projectDir = new File("/home/jaibatrik/StudioProjects/sugar/library")
```

instead of

```
project(':sugar').projectDir = new File(getLocalProperty('sugar.dir'))
```

But, as I work in multiple systems with different operating systems, it is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Might be relevant - the same code worked in my MacBook and in my Linux machine, I renamed the root directory of the project.

Comment: Try to use **settingsDir** instead of **rootDir**

Comment: BTW, I prefer a different cross-platform approach: instead of overriding **projectDir** in **settings.gradle**, you can create a symbolic link `sugar` to `/home/jaibatrik/StudioProjects/sugar/library`. This way you don't need to mess with **local.properties**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion, the problem was with having double quotes in the local.properties file. The compiler was treating the path to the directory as a file name.

Using

```
sugar.dir=/home/jaibatrik/StudioProjects/sugar/library
```

rather than

```
sugar.dir="/home/jaibatrik/StudioProjects/sugar/library"
```

solved the problem.